# Change UIWebView Cursor Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, editor

Im developing an editor view using UIWebview. I want to change the default UIWebView cursor blue colour to my customised colour.

I tried to change the cursor colour by using the following code. But it did not work.

```
[self.editorView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Any suggestion would be helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find the correct Safary webkit property that applies to the cursor color, and use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method of UIWebView.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTapHighlightColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)';"]; 
    }
```

I'm not sure if webkitTapHighlightColor is what you are trying to change, but you can look for more properties on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006510-SW5

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is for to change the tap highlight color. I want to change the cursor color. For example, while typing the default cursor color will be blue. All I want is to change the blue color to my customised color.

Comment: typing where? inside a input field that is inside de web you are showing in the WebView?

Comment: If what you want to change is the caret that is shown in the input fields inside a UIWebView... that is browser dependent, you will have top write a JavaScript script to do it.